# Change values of subtotal in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, payment

I have the following code so far, I want to compute my subtotal to get the total payment. Can anyone help?

```
$viewx = mysql_query("select distinct toorderid from ordercontainer where toordercategory='$ordercategory' and customerid=$customerid") or die("Could not execute the select query." .mysql_error());
while($rowx = mysql_fetch_array($viewx))
{
    $id = $rowx['toorderid'];

    $view = mysql_query("select * from products where menuid = '$id' and status = 'Active'") or die("Could not execute the select query" .mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($view))
    {
        $item = $row['item'];
        $details = $row['details'];
        $price = $row['price'];

        echo '<tr><td>'.$item;
        echo '<div style="margin:0px 0px 0px 5px">'.$details.'</div></td>';
        echo '<td><select name="qty" onChange="" style="width:50px"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option></select></td>';
        echo '<td align="center">'.$price.'</td>';
        $qty = ;
        $totalprice = ;
        $subtotal = ($totalprice * $qty);
        $totalpayment = $subtotal; 
        echo '<td align="center">'.$subtotal.' Php</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're stuck on?

Comment: when you read those code there are missing parts and the computation on the loop inside while im listing the value coming out from the database. I have to sum up those values so I may have the total payment and when I adjust the select option the subtotal and total payment also changes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all... you are printing a select box in PHP... that's not the problem, the problem is PHP is expecting the value of the select box in return to compute the total price. A better solution would be to have PHP write everything as it is, except for the computing part... then have JAvascript compute the total price for you in the onchange event of the select box. And then have jquery append the result to the subtotal area.

Good luck.